# Invoke generic method on all the derived types in type hierarchy

Tags: c#

Let's say we have the following type hierarchy:

```
public abstract class Base {}
public class A : Base {}
public class B : Base {}
```

I need to perform the same operations on all the derived types from `Base`. This is what I came up

```
public IList<T> DoWork<T>(string entityPath) where T : Base {
    // get 'json' using 'entityPath'
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
}
```

Now my problem is to somehow invoke `DoWork()` on all the derived classes in a for-loop in the consumer's class. What I was hoping to work was something like:

```
var entities = new Dictionary<string, Type> {
    ['a', TypeOf(A)],
    ['b', TypeOf(B)]
}
foreach(var e in entitties) {
    DoWork<e.Value>(e.Key)
}
```

Which is obviously not working.

If this approach is entirely flawed, I would love to know the alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use generics if you don't know the type at compile time, but fortunately, `JsonConvert.DeserialiseObject` has an overload that takes a string and a `Type`!

Therefore, you can add an overload of `DoWork` that is non-generic:

```
public object DoWork(string entityPath, Type type) {
    // get 'json' using 'entityPath'
    var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, listType);
}
```

And then call it in a for loop like this:

```
foreach(var e in entitties) {
    DoWork(e.Key, e.Value); // why are you ignoring the return value?
}
```

Comment: In the actual code, the return value is not ignored. Does the first sentence mean that even the base type cannot be used in a polymorphic way (i.e. `DoWork<Base>(path)` where Base is actually an instance of `A`)?

Comment: In the statement `DoWork<Base>(path)`, `Base` is just `Base`. It can't be `A`. `Base` is a type, and a _type_ can't be an instance of another _type_, so I am not quite sure what you mean by that... @havij

Comment: oh nvm that was a dumb question, I need to study more about generics, thanks!