# How to deserialize a model to its type if the Type is supplied

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json-deserialization, converters

I'm trying to write a function which accepts a serialized json object (which matches an object definition class (model) ) and given the Type, deserialize it to that model.
There are several models,..in the code below I use *TCustomerModel*  (just a class of properties)

From my API(s), I want to call this function, pass it the json object which matches one of my models, 
and also pass it the ModelType (i.e. in this case *TCustomerModel*
Thus far, what I've seen or tried does not work.

as a simple example. (This works, ..but I want a function which can do this just having the Type passed to it and not having to explicitly create myModel on each and every type ).

```
 TCustomerModel   myModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TCustomerModel>(jsonModel);
```

Code:

```
public class DeserializeModelValidator
{
    public Object ValidateModel (Type objectType, object theModel)
    {
        objectModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<theModel>, typeof(objectType));
        // etc
    }
}
```

Calling Code:  (from within an API)

```
DeserializeModelValidator validator = new DeserializeModelValidator();
validator.ValidateModel(typeof(TCustomerModel), objectModel);
```

Comment: You want to deserialize an object that is already deserialized? `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<theModel>, typeof(objectType));` you deserialize from string to an object not from a random `object`

Comment: I think [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385714/invoke-generic-method-on-all-the-derived-types-in-type-hierarchy/57385751#57385751) might help...

Comment: Thanks, but it gives me an error.
    Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Catalyst.Mvc.Controllers.API.TCustomerModel]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: There's a non-generic overload of [`DeserializeObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm) that accepts a `Type` as a parameter, is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic extension method for this.

```
public static class DeserializeModelValidator
{
    public static T ValidateModel<T>(this string serializedJson)
    {
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serializedJson);
        // etc
        return result;
    }
}
```

You would call the extension method as:

```
var myModel = jsonModel.ValidateModel<TCustomerModel>();
```

Comment: But how then do i pass my serialized json string object to it, so it can be deserialized into an object of type "TCustomerModel"?

Comment: @NealRogers  The extension method already knows about the serialized object string when you call it. In my example `jsonModel.ValidateModel<TCustomerModel>()`, the `jsonModel` is your serialized json string object.  The `.ValidateModel` calls the extension method on the string. The `<TCustomerMode>` is the type used to deserialize the string object.  You may want to go over generics and extension methods in C# to better understand my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found this, which works. Now all I need is a way of using the Type variable to instantiate a class of that type.
e.g. 
    useType CLasstype = new useType();

but, thats a different question.

```
public object DeserializeModelr(string value, Type useType, params JsonConverter[] converters)
{
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( value, useType,  converters);
    dynamic DataModel = Convert.ChangeType(result, useType);

    etc
}
```